# Intellij IDEA > Cucumber Test Results don't display Scenario name

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber

#### Problem:

When running my Cucumber Acceptance tests from Intellij, the Test Results don't display the scenario name, just `<no name>` - making it difficult/impossible to determine which Scenario actually failed!

e.g.

[image]

I'm using JDK8 with Intellij IDEA 15 Community Edition (Build #IC-143.2287) with the following Intellij IDEA plugins:

- Cucumber for Java (v 143.382) - [github.com](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-plugins/tree/master/cucumber-java) / [plugins.jetbrains.com](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7212)
- Cucumber for Groovy (v 143.382) - [github.com](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-plugins/tree/master/cucumber-groovy) / [plugins.jetbrains.com](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7213)

**The following Cucumber libraries (gradle):**

```groovy
testCompile "info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.2.4"
testCompile "info.cukes:cucumber-java8:1.2.4"
testCompile "info.cukes:cucumber-spring:1.2.4"
```

**This is my `AcceptanceTests.groovy` file:**

```groovy
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        strict = false,
        plugin = ["pretty", "html:build/reports/cucumber"],
        tags = ['~@ignore']
)
public class AcceptanceTests {}
```

#### Just wondering:

- Is there anyway to display the scenario name?
- Is it something I'm doing OR is it just not implemented yet? (OR does it exist in the Intellij IDEA Ultimate Edition?)
- Who can I suggest this feature to, if it doesn't exist yet?

#### Update - 21/03/2016

I've forwarded my question to the author (Andrey Vokin) and raised an issue - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-153338 .

Comment: Could you add a feature file that shows this behaviour?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have same problem, and found where it's coming from in my case. For "scenario" at least, it seems to come from dots (".") : remove them from your scenario description and see what happens.

Comment: As of today,above jetbrains issue is still open, work around is to remove dots in scenario description.  Thank you Vicent.

Comment: In my case the dot was in the feature text.

Comment: Thanks for posting this!

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing the same problem, but I haven't used any dots (".") in scenario description. Though the full stop (dot) was present in the Feature file description and after removing that it worked for me.

Feature file description:
[image: Feature file description]

After result how it looks like:
[image: After result how it looks like]